# How to know if a device is being accessed in Windows?

Tags: c#, c++, c

I was wondering, is there a way to know that my hardware device is being accessed by any application in C/C++ or C#? For example: like on video chats web applications. Usually Adobe flash asks that application wants to access the device. Is there a ways to do that in a desktop application on windows?

What i am trying to do is that, i want to monitor for those API calls which comes in for accessing the devices like microphone. I just want to prompt user that some application is using a device.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do that.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! I recommend you check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and head back when you have a specific programming-related question.

Comment: Hi EkoostikMartin, Could you please share how do we achieve that??

Comment: I never got a solution to this problem :(

Comment: But someone suggested me to write a device driver. But i have no experience in that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can problematically deal with you hardware devices of your PC. And before access that device with your code ( Assume that you are invoking a method supplied by that device's vendow through its API), before access you can prompt your user and ask whether he grant to access that device.

eg - Pseudo Code

```
MessageBox.Show("This app needs to access your camera");

var result = MessageBox Result

if(result == true)
{
Access code to the device... etc.......
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I wanted to know how do i monitor my hardware. I can print the messageboxes, i know about that but i want to filter each request that is made to a hardware.